# Background-color problem in dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, css

Look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/esTzk/

How come the color on my #header won't apply ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a height or hide the overflow and it will. Either will work in this case.

```
#header{
  background:#2b2b2b;
  color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  height:200px; /* overrides float calculations */
  overflow:hidden; /* clears floats */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/esTzk/1/

Comment: Yeah it does :S Is it because of the positioning it don't think that the UL and LI are in it ?

Comment: It's because of the floating elements inside the `#header` container not being cleared.

Comment: Thanks but the overflow will hide my submenus but it works with a given height.

Comment: Ah nice yea I didn't play with your menu system but that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Give your header a height, because you dont want it be greater than a certain value anyway:

```
#header{
  background-color:#2b2b2b;
  color:#fff
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
}
```

a better solution would be to move the div with clear both inside the header.

```
<div id="header">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li>Service Provider
      <ul>
        <li>Vendor / Manufacturer</li>
        <li>Service Type</li>
        <li>Service Technician</li>
      </ul>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </li>
    <li>Cities & Stations
      <ul>
        <li>Stations</li>
        <li>Station Owner</li>
      </ul>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </li>
    <li>Firefighter</li>
    <li>PPE Management</li>
    <li>Care & Maintenance</li>
    <li><a href="index.php?logout=yes">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add for your knowledge, it is because of the float:left in the #nav li selector. Because the elements inside the #header div are floated the #header div is set to height=0. That's why it won't display the background color before you specify a height for it or clear the float.